# Export dataset to new Access 2010 .accdb file

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a asp.net C# application in which a user wants to export a report to the new Access 2010+ accdb file. The data is loaded into a datatable. How can I export this datatable into a standalone foo.accdb that access 2010+ can open?

I'm new to this app and currently its doing this via some Common.ExportDotNet2.dll but was exporting to the .mdb file. I'm trying to upgrade if you must to the new .accdb file extension.

Its currently called like so.

```
FName = CommonMdbExport.ExportTable(ds.Tables[0], FLocation, FName);
```

Below is the metadata from that DLL.

```
#region Assembly Common.ExportDotNet2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null
// Bin\Common.ExportDotNet2.dll
#endregion

using System.Data;

namespace Common.ExportDotNet2
{
    public class CommonMdbExport
    {
    public CommonMdbExport();

    public static string ExportDataSet(DataSet ds, string path, string fileName = "TestData.Mdb");
    public static string ExportTable(DataTable dt, string path, string fileName = "TestData.Mdb");
    }
}
```

I've seen info saying I can use Microsofts.ACE DLL but couldn't find how to use that.

Comment: Start with [How to create an Access database by using ADOX and Visual C# .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317881/how-to-create-an-access-database-by-using-adox-and-visual-c-.net) for actually creating a new accdb file. From there, you can use ADO.NET and database tools built into Visual Studio for opening the new database and inserting new data.

Comment: I see that you already asked this exact question a few days ago and it was put on hold. That happened because your question is too broad and has too much extra information.  A better question would have been "How can I create an new Access database (2010 accdb) from c#"?  The code you shared was not helpful since it does not show any detail of what you want to do.  Lastly, please don't ignore messages and suggestions on the website.  The hold message suggested editing the question to make it more clear, not repost the exact same question.